# Json Schema validation: do not allow fields other than those declared in schema

Tags: json, validation, jsonschema

Suppose that I have schema like

```
fname: string
lname: string
age: string
```

None of them are required. User can send me any of those attributes above but nothing else that is not declared. They can pass me `fname`, `lname` and `age` or all. But if they pass me all and additional property like `middle_name` the message should be rejected.

How would I define a schema like this?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

You can create a [json-schema](http://json-schema.org/) and use the option:

```
additionalProperties = false
```

That way you only allow the attributes defined in properties. In your case:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "fname": {"type": "string"},
        "lname": {"type": "string"},
        "age": {"type": "string"}
    },
    "additionalProperties": false
}
```